# Ionic 3, Muliple toggle filter options

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m trying to create a filter to learn more about ionic. I got pretty far but now I’m stuck.
I’m trying to add a toggle for each option, when the user activates a toggle those options needs to be show. So far I can do it with a dropdown menu. But there are some things that can be done allot better.

Right now, at my provider I store data like so;

```
gerechten = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "name 1", "soort": "pasta"},
{ "id": 2, "name": "name 2", "soort": "pasta1"},
{ "id": 3, "name": "name 3", "soort": "pasta2"},
{ "id": 4, "name": "name 4", "soort": "pasta3"},
{ "id": 5, "name": "name 5", "soort": "pasta1"},
{ "id": 6, "name": "name 6", "soort": "pasta"},
```

]

And I filter it like so, notice I need to add || for each option, so right now I can only filter with 2 options. Is there a way to do this automatic for all the kind of options I have?

```
     query(params?: any) {
    let returnData=this.gerechten;
    if (!params) {
      return returnData;
    }
    console.log("filtering with this",params);

    if(params['soort']!=="" || params['soort2']!==""){
      returnData = returnData.filter((item) => {
        if(params['soort']==item['soort'] || params['soort2']==item['soort']){
          return item;
        }
      });
    }
    return returnData;
  }

My filterpage.ts looks like this

    export class DataFilterPage {
  filterData={
    ingredienten:"",
    soort:"",
    soort2:""
  }

  soorten=[]
  soortenNew=[]

  constructor(
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public gerechtenprovider: GerechtenProvider
  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DataFilterPage');

    this.soorten = this.gerechtenprovider.gerechten.map((item)=>{
      return item.soort;
    })
    this.soortenNew =  Array.from(new Set(this.soorten ));
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.filterData);
  }
```

And my filterpage.html is as follow (I’m able to show the toggle’s, but they don’t work)

```
    <ion-item>
  <ion-label>soort 1</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="filterData.soort" interface="action-sheet">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let soort of soortenNew" value="{{soort}}">{{soort}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>


<ion-item>
    <ion-label>soort 2</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="filterData.soort2" interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let soort of soortenNew" value="{{soort}}">{{soort}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>



<ion-item *ngFor="let soort of soortenNew" [attr.soort]="soort">
    <span item-start class="dot"></span>
  <ion-label>{{soort}}</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="filterData.soort"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>



<ion-item>
  <button ion-button full (click)="dismiss()">Filter</button>
</ion-item>
```

Anny help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution you have to filter elements is create an [Angular Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Your html should be like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let soort of soorten | soortenFiltered:filterData">
  <span item-start class="dot"></span>
  <ion-label>{{soort}}</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="filterData.soort"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

and you have to create a pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'soortFiltered',
})
export class SoortFilteredPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(soorten: any[], filteredData: any) {
    let myNewSoortenFiltered;
    myNewSoortenFiltered = soorten.filter((item) => {
      if(filteredData['soort'] == item['soort'] || filteredData['soort2'] == item['soort']) {
        return item;
      }
    });
    return myNewSoortenFiltered;
  }
}
```

Something like this.

This way you can reutilize the filter created in other components.

Comment: What extra's does this pipe bring? I don't see how i can work with the toggle's now.

Comment: The pipe bring the power of filtering data in ngFor. Then, you don't need to filter it in the component.